# True or false that S is a closed set

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Let $f : \mathbb R → \mathbb R$ be a continuous function and let S be the set of points where f has a local maximum.
Then S is a closed set. Is it true or false?

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=-x \sin (\frac  1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $0$ for $x=0$. Then $f$ has a local minimum at the points $\frac 1 {(2n+1)\pi}$ but it does not have  a local minimum at $0$.

Here is a plot: [image]

Comment: I have taken the liberty to add a plot, to visualize what is going on.

Comment: @G.Chiusole Fantastic! Thank you.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy sorry but I still don't see why

Comment: In a neighborhood of $1/(2n+1)\pi$ the function is non-negative and it vanishes at $1/(2n+1)\pi$. [Note that $\sin x$ is non-positive near $(2n+1)\pi$].

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy but I still don't see which set is S if it's closed or not

Comment: $\frac 1 {(2n+1)\pi} \in S$ for each $n$, $\frac 1 {(2n+1)\pi} \to 0$ and $0 \notin S$. Hence $S$ is not closed. @JuanSolo